# Json Input Path Expression for this JSON

Tags: java, json, pentaho, etl, jsonpath

I have this json :

```
{
  "1022": {
    "019848878696": {
      "qty": 3,
      "price": 279
    },
    "029017645370": {
      "qty": 4,
      "price": 349
    }
  },
  "1024": {
    "019848878623": {
      "qty": 3,
      "price": 23
    },
    "029017665370": {
      "qty": 4,
      "price": 3434
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to put the correct Input Json path for each element inside but i couldn't do that. especially i want to get the `id` and `code` as separated fields.

for example :
[image]

Where :

[image]

Comment: What you are trying to do is not recommended. Here `1022` and `10198488786961` are keys and not values. It is always recommended to do this:  `id: 1022` and `code: 10198488786961`

Comment: Where does that JSON structure come from? What's that table for? What language(s)/technique(s) do you use? Please improve that question.... it's not clear what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, plain JSON (outside a JavaScript context) is intended to have a known structure, where your example has arbitrary keys. For PDI, you'll have better luck with the Modified JavaScript step (using Object.keys) than the JSON Input step.